# Static variables when the application is launched from another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a doubt regarding the behavior of Android with a static variable created in an Activity. I created a **static** boolean variable which is true if the running device API is < 11 and false if not.

```
public static boolean apiLower11;
```

i assign a value to it in `onCreate` (just now i thinked why i didn't do directly `public static boolean apiLower11 = !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);`) of my `MainActivity` which is the activity where my application start. This variable is used in other Activities too (it's the important part).

Now starts my question:

Suppose that one day you can open the application by starting another activity (via a notification?) without going through the main activity, what is the value of my static variable? The main activity has not been created then has not received any value right?

What if the Main Activity is destroyed while the user is browsing my application (I know, Android kills other process not what the user is using..) but is possibile this kind of scenario? And what will happen to my static variable?

As far as i know: static variables are created when the class is loaded so which will remains alive until the classloader is alive. If i put the

```
apiLower11 = !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);
```

inside a `static` block i will not have this problem?

The value is assigned one time and i avoid this assign every time the onCreate of the activity is called.

I think as alternative to use a class which extends Application and put this variable so it should be alive during the entire life cycle of the application.

Anyway, the big mistake i could see by himself here is the wrong thing to give the value to the variable in the onCreate method instead of `static` block

Comment: As you mentioned, just use what `Build` provides when you need it. BTW, `! (>=)` is `<`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yup i just write it wrong. Is true when API < 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the static variable has not been initialized,it will get a default value(apiLower11 will be false).

so

> Suppose that one day you can open the application by starting another activity (via a notification?) without going through the main activity, what is the value of my static variable? The main activity has not been created then has not received any value right?

The answer is your static variable apiLower11 is false.

> apiLower11 = !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);inside a static block i will not have this problem?

The answer is yes,you can do it,because the static block will be executed just after the ClassLoader loaded  the MainActivity.class

Comment: The class itself remains "alive" just the Activity is destroyed so here we don't have any possibility to lose the value if the activity gets destroyed right? I think I just did a big confusion between the two things.

Comment: Yes,the activity which is destroyed is just an object,but the class(MainActivity) still alive in the ClassLoader.When a object died,all variables in it would be destoryed except the static ones which will be alive as the ClassLoader still alive.

Comment: Great, everything is like "normal" Java about it. Thanks.. just by reading this question again today I understand how it could sound stupid. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull this out into another class:

```
public class ApiLevel {
    public static boolean isLowerThan11() {
         return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of calling `MainActivity.apiLower11` when you need to check, you call `ApiLevel.isLowerThan11()`.

Comment: Uh.. great.. strange how I didn't think about it.. Would be great to know anyway if the kind of problems with static variables in activity class exists or it's just me making useless problems

Comment: If you _really_ wanted to use a static in an Activity, you'd declare it something like: `public static boolean apiLower11 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;`. This will get initialised when it's accessed (I think). The way you're doing it now, you most definitely could encounter issues where it hasn't been initialised - in which case it defaults to false!